# Windows 10 In-App Purchase Testing

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, windows-store

I tested the implementation of my purchases in the simulator using CurrentAppSimulator. Now I'd like to test the actual purchases in the store. Is there a way to test purchasing the products without actually purchasing them similar to how you create test iTunes accounts during iOS In-App purchase testing?

Also, I couldn't find any documentation on how to test live purchases, only on how to use the simulator. Does anyone know of an official reference?